# Classify Reserved words to categories

Tags: programming-languages, theory

Im taking a course called Programming Languages and this particular subject isnt explained very well and I dont know how it is called in english (I study in hebrew) so I cant really search for it online.
I wanted to know what are the categories to which we can classify all the reserved words of a certain programming language (pascal in my case) and what does every category mean?
Thanks alot!.

Answer (score 1):

You can classify reserved words by their purpose, e.g.:

- declarations

  - variable declarations
  - procedure declarations
  - function declarations
  - module declarations
- control flow

  - loops

    - condition-controlled loops
    - counter-controlled loops
  - conditionals
  - switch statements
- the `with` reserved word, which is unique to Pascal I think

etc.

It is best to explain these by reference to a particular programming language like Pascal.

Just look at the table of contents of a programming language specification.